# Resolve error in lm execution - error in contrasts - no variable with just one level found

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to run a linear regression on a very large dataset and am receiving the error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

From searching online, I understand that this error is because my dataset contains a factor variable with just one level. However, I have thoroughly checked the variable in my dataset.

```
values_count <- sapply(lapply(temp, unique), length)
which(values_count == 1) # returned integer(0)

str(temp) # did not reveal any factor variables with just one level
```

I am unable to provide a reproducible example of the dataset as it is very large. Could anyone help to resolve this issue? If any additional information is required, please let me know and I will try to provide it.

Comment: It could be that if you have missing data, once you remove all the observations with at least one missing value you have a factor that has a single observed value.  To check, make a subset of your data that only includes the variables in your model and then call `na.omit()` on it.  Do the same diagnostic you did above to that list wise deleted dataset to see if you can identify the problem that way.

Comment: That was indeed the case. Many thanks, @DaveArmstrong!